# Onesignal Badge count increment is not working

Tags: php, ios, swift, cakephp, onesignal

In Onesignal api, I have added isIos => true,ios_badgeType => Increase,ios_badgeCount => 1,content_available => true in the field array.
But the badge count always remains as 1, it's not increasing with multiple messages.

This is my payload details : `$fields = array( 'app_id' => "xxxxxx", 'included_segments' => array('All'), 'data' => array( "notification_type" => "update" ), 'contents' => $content, 'subtitle' => $subtitle, 'headings' => $heading, 'isIos' => true, 'ios_badgeType' => "Increase", 'ios_badgeCount' => 1, 'content_available' => true );`

Comment: Add code what you are doing

Comment: remove ios_badgeCount this field. May be your problem will solve

Comment: Your payload details? What is complete payload keys and format?

Comment: This is my payload details :$fields = array(
            'app_id' => "xxxxxx",
            'included_segments' => array('All'),
            'data' => array(
                "notification_type" => "update"
            ),
            'contents' => $content,
            'subtitle' => $subtitle,
            'headings' => $heading,
            'isIos' => true,
            'ios_badgeType' => "Increase",
            'ios_badgeCount' => 1,
            'content_available' => true
        );

Comment: +1 I am experiencing the same issue. One thing I did notice was if you set ios_badgeCount to 2. The app's badge icon will always be 2, so it is as if we are using the SetTo ios_badgeType. I reached out to OneSignal's support team, so I will post an update here if/when I hear back from them.

Comment: @chiragshah you will get a 400 response from OneSignal if you don't include the ios_badgeCount in the body of the request

Comment: I am having the same problem...

Comment: @M.Carlson any updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-app-groups-setup in detail.

The name of your app group should be

> group.{your_bundle_id}.onesignal
>
> So for example, if your application's bundle identifier is
>   com.test.app, your app group name should be
>   group.com.test.app.onesignal.
>
> [Assign the group to both
>   target](https://files.readme.io/9e17c8c-OneSignal_Xcode_app_groups_capabilites.png).
>
> 1. Open your Info.plist file and add a new OneSignal_app_groups_key as a String type.
> 2. Enter the group name you checked in the last step as it's value.
> 3. Make sure to do the same for the Info.plist under the OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension folder.

Comment: Is this necesary for Ionic Apps?

Comment: @Codeicus yes this is needed for ios ionic apps still

Answer (score 3):

You must add Notification Extension in order to get badge auto update. Please follow the [link to setup](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup).

Also, need to create app group and assign both bundle id to that particular group. Please see the section -

> In order for your application to be able to let push notifications
>   increment/decrement the badge count, you need to set up an App Group
>   for your application.

[See here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup#section-6-add-app-groups-optional-but-recommended-)